# Unity overlap sphere detecting no collidiers

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

I have a problem concerning the overlap between two cubes. I have a level that is populated with many 1x1x1 cubes in 3D, the positions of which are changing. I want to test if, for a given position, two of the cubes are overlapping. To do this, I called Phsyics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc with a radius of .25 at the position (which is at the center of the overlapping cubes) to return a list of colliders. If more than one collider is returned, then two of the colliders are overlapping. That was the idea. The call instead returned no colliders. Here is a 2D cross-sectional illustration of what I am doing:

[image]

I believe that no colliders are found because the entire overlap sphere lies *inside* of the cube collider. But the unity docs say that Phsyics.OverlapSphere...

> Returns an array with all colliders touching or inside the sphere.

I would've thought that, although Physics.OverlapSphere lies inside the cube collider, the cube collider is still technically inside the overlap sphere. Can anyone explain this to me or offer a workaround method to find an array of all the colliders at a given point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue stems from the way Unity has worded the docs. In your case the sphere is inside the collider, where overlapsphere returns colliders inside the sphere.

I am not sure what kind of scale we are operating on here, but one approach would be to use [Vector3.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) to compare all the blocks to your position. If you have thousands of blocks you could consider merging the two methods, where you have a large overlapsphere that then takes the result and narrows it down using the distance formula.

Hopefully this helps! :)

Comment: Using distance is one way to do it, but in my case would involve iterating through the level objects. Is there an easier way to simply return all colliders that contain a point?

Comment: @rbjacob not that I know of no. Distance could also be faster because you are not dealing with colliders. If you are worried about iterating through non-block objects just maintain a static list of every block you have created and use that. Or try my trick where you do an overlap with a radius of 1.1 and then use the distance formula on the results to find the closest.

Comment: Yes, that is what I decided to do, using a RaycastAll in my case to narrow down the search and then using distance. Thanks!